# ftp_put works but fopen("ftp://... fails on live hosting

Tags: php, ftp, fopen

I'm trying to write a file to an ftp server in chunks. Its working on my development environment using the following stripped down code:

```
$fp = fopen("ftp://user:pass@host/file.txt","a");
fwrite($fp, '1');
fclose($fp);
```

however when I try it on my live server its failing silently. I've enabled error reporting and ensured allow_url_fopen is On. Is there anything else that could be blocking this? Live PHP version is 5.4.0, Testing 5.4.3. Also, if I use ftp_put on my live hosting that works.